# How to display chart data in vertical direction using dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.charting

I'm using DOJO column charts in my application. Here i have a requirement to display the value on top of the bar. That can be achieved using the label property. After doing this i had another problem i.e. If the value is large then all values are getting overlapped as shown below

[image]

In order to overcome this overlapping issue i was trying to display the label in vertical direction. Can you guys help me solving this issue

Comment: May be this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6948229/how-to-deal-with-overlapping-x-axis-labels-in-dojo-chart) might help

Comment: Can you add your code for the chart so I can see how you are defining your labels?

Answer (score 0):

You can rotate the labels using the "rotation" attribute when you create the axis
For example:

```
chart.addAxis("x", {labels: xLabels, rotation: 90});
```